# Setting and clearing text fields programmatically using Angular

Tags: jquery, html, angular

I am pretty new to `angular` and I am facing a problem. Namely I am trying to input text type, then clear it up again and then set it again without interacting with the UI.

So here I have a little peace of the `text` fields:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="titleText">Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="titleText" id="titleText" aria-describedby="titleText" placeholder="Title">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="authorText">Author</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="authorText" id="authorText" placeholder="Author">
</div>
```

And here is the `angular` part:

```
authorText : string;
titleText : string;
durationText : string;
genreText : string;

//Set the values
this.durationText = this.song.duration; //Just a string
this.authorText = this.song.author; 
this.genreText = this.song.genre;
this.titleText = this.song.title;

//Clear the values
jQuery('#editSongDialog').find("input,textarea,select")
    .val('')
    .end()
    .find("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]")
    .prop("checked", "")
    .end();
```

So when I am trying to set the values and clear the values then set the values again (with new values), the all fields end up empty. But when I try to set the values and then override them with new values then it works.

My guess is that the `.prop("checked", "")` gives the fields a value that does not accept a `string` and thus it is not filling it.

Comment: **do not do this with jQuery**.  Update your model and let it update your view.

Comment: To add to the prior comment, since you are using `[(ngModel)]`, your values will automatically update in your UI based on the values in your code. Simply set `this.titleText = ''` to clear the value.

Comment: @DeborahK alright, will do, but why is using jquery bad?

Comment: It interferes with how Angular is already working, messes with change detection, and somewhat defeats the point of what Angular is doing with two way binding. :-)

Comment: And one last question if you do not mind.. how would you clear `class="form-control-file"` or the part where I can choose a file.

Comment: Can you add the code for that to your question?

Comment: @DeborahK yes sorry, I was away. But i edited the question

Comment: @DeborahK since the topic is different, I made a new question for it. [link to new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53549512/clearing-select-field-in-angular?noredirect=1#comment93965845_53549512)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya, don't use Jquery...
One option that is clean is to use `reactive forms` or just `FormControls`.
Reactive forms or model driven forms will make it easy to update/manipulate the form controls by manipulating the `model` or the control itself..doesn't matter where the change is coming from, server or events...

You can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms), but here is a quick example.

FormControl example

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="titleText">Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControl]="titleText" id="titleText" aria-describedby="titleText" placeholder="Title">
</div>
```

relevant parts of the controller:

```
titleText: FormControl = new FormControl();
titleText.setValue('My great song'); // sets the value of the input
titleText.reset(); // clears the input
```

FormGroup example

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="submitForm()">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="titleText">Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="titleText" id="titleText" aria-describedby="titleText" placeholder="Title">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="authorText">Author</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="authorText" id="authorText" placeholder="Author">
</div>
```

and the controller

```
form: FormGroup;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        'titleText': ['initial value'],
        'authorText': [],
    });
}

 ngOnInit() {
    this.form.get('titleText').setValue('Great Song'); //set value of the control
    this.form.get('titleText').clear(); //clear the control
    this.form.setValue({titleText:'Great Song', authorText:'Gaga'}); //update all values in group
    this.form.patchValue({authorText:'Metallica'}); //update single value in group
    this.form.reset() //clear entire form   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I was told, it is bad practice to use `jQuery` and the easiest solution here would be using :

```
this.titleText = ''
```