# Clearing select field in angular

Tags: angular, select

How can I separately clear these fields?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="lrcfile">Lyrics file (.lrc)</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="lrcfile" accept=".lrc" (change)="setLrcFile($event)" >
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="pitchfile">Pitches file (.txt)</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="pitchfile" accept=".txt" (change)="setPitchfile($event)">
</div>

lrcfile: any;
pitchfile: any;
```

Setting the file:

```
setPitchfile(fileInput: any) {
    for (var i =  fileInput.target.files.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
         var file = fileInput.target.files[i];
         this.pitchfile = file;
    }
}
```

Setting them to `' '` or to `null` like most sources recommend does not do anything.

```
this.pitchfile = null;
```

It still shows like it is there. In this picture you can see that the `lrc` file that I had chosen before stays like it was and I have not made any changes to the `txt` file just to show how it should look like.

[image]

**EDIT**

I did manage to clear it, but it clears a bit too much.. with this I could clear all of my `<input>` fields, but I only want the ones with the `type = "file"`.

In my `HTML` I have other `<input>'s` like..

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="durationText">Song Duration (ms)</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="durationText" id="durationText" placeholder="Song Duration">
</div>
```

Which are not `type = "file"`. I managed to clear them all using `jquery`.

```
jQuery('#addNewSongDialog').find("input,textarea,select")
        .val('')
        .end()
```

Is there maybe a way to use this to only clear `type = "file"` fields?

Comment: “No file chosen”...hmm, looks gone to me.

Comment: @BenSteward I am just showing how it stays and how it should look like. Will edit the post.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33796481/7872063

Comment: @BenSteward so there is no way to clear it?

Comment: I don’t know I stopped reading. You should keep reading though.

Comment: Where are you setting that default? I don't see it set in your code?

Comment: @DeborahK added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here is some code that works for me:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lrcfile">Lyrics file (.lrc)</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="lrcfile" accept=".lrc" (change)="setLrcFile($event)" >
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="pitchfile">Pitches file (.txt)</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="pitchfile" accept=".txt" #file (change)="setPitchfile($event)">
</div>
<button (click)="clear(file)">Clear Pitches</button>
`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
  pitchfile = '';

  constructor() {
  }

  clear(file) {
    file.value = '';
  }

  setPitchfile(fileInput: any) {
    for (var i = fileInput.target.files.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var file = fileInput.target.files[i];
      this.pitchfile = file;
    }
  }
}
```

The associated stackblitz is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-swrvew

On this line:

```
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" 
           id="pitchfile" accept=".txt" 
           #file (change)="setPitchfile($event)">
```

I added a template reference variable (#file) that provides a reference to the control.

On the Clear button, I pass that along to the clear method. I then use the `value` property of the control to clear the text.

Does that help?

Comment: Wierd.. when I tried `file.value = '';` it did not work, but now it somehow does. Anyways thank a lot for your help. It is working now.